# Using regex, but it does not remove html tags in excel sheet

Tags: regex, excel, excel-2003, vba

I trying to remove the html tags using the code below but it does not do anything. I have tried running it again but to no use. Could someone please advise what could be the issue. Attaching a snapshot of the file with html tags. For info, the data comes from the MS Access and the MS Access links to Sharepoint lists.

[image]

```
Sub Import_AccessData()
 Dim strtKeyMsgRange As Range
 Dim KeyMsgRange As Range
 Dim KeyMsgRangeCell As Range
 Dim endKeyMsgRangeCell As Range

Set strtKeyMsgRange = Range("B2")
Set endKeyMsgRange = Range("AC13")

Set KeyMsgRange = Range(strtKeyMsgRange, endKeyMsgRange)

For Each KeyMsgRangeCell In KeyMsgRange
   a = StripHTML(KeyMsgRangeCell)
   KeyMsgRangeCell.Value = a
Next KeyMsgRangeCell

End Sub


Public Function StripHTML(cell As Range) As String
     Dim RegEx As Object
     Set RegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

     Dim sInput As String
     Dim sOut As String


     sInput = cell.Value

     With RegEx
   .Global = True
   .IgnoreCase = True
   .MultiLine = True
   .Pattern = "<[^>]+>" 'Regular Expression for HTML Tags.
   .Pattern = "&nbsp;"
   .Pattern = "&amp;"
 End With

 sOut = RegEx.Replace(sInput, "")
 StripHTML = sOut
 Set RegEx = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: regexes manipulating html only reads to madness.

Comment: I think [Jeff Atwood](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html) says it best.

Comment: I am not hell-bent to use regex. I just have a problem at hand(viz html tags that come from importing data from Sharepoint) and I will employ any method to get rid of those tags. Any suggestions please?

Comment: @MarcB: To be fair, asker isn't trying to *parse* HTML, only strip out tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the Pattern property multiple times, it will only retain the last value assigned (`&amp;`).

You need to use 3 regular expressions(`"<[^>]+>" => ""`, `"&nbsp;" => " "`, `"&amp;" => "&"`), or one expression that matches all of your inputs (`"(&amp;)|(&nbsp;)|(<[^>]+>)" => ""`) to actually do this.

Comment: Thanks everyone for looking into this. ("(&amp;)|(&nbsp;)|(<[^>]+>)") worked. Thanks Joaquim R.